# Session values can overwrite local variables

Tags: php

I am developing a Php project on LAMP server. Now i face a problem on session variable and local variable.In my systems first.php set the value in session and then in second.php , i set these session variable to my local variable. Then take action and clear the Session values.But i also loose the value in my local variable.How can i solve this problem?
Structure of coding flow is like as following

In first.php

```
$_SESSION['var'] = "test";
```

In second.php

```
$var = $_SESSION['var'] ;
$_SESSION['var'] = "";
echo $var;           // at this time ,i cant also see my local variable values
```

Comment: Did you check before `$_SESSION['var'] = "";` ?

Comment: Yes, i do it and there is value in $_SESSION['var'] and also in local variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have [register_globals](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) turned on. This is indeed very bad, because it allows injection of variables in your script by a end-user (using cookies, per example).

It's deprecated. Turn it off, quick (in php.ini, or if you can't, in a .htaccess with a `php_flag` directive). If your script relies on it, change your script.

Comment: Yes , now i solve like this by setting the register_globals off in .htaccess file of my project.Thank a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If that is all you have in your first & second script, then you certainly missed `session_start()` in the beginning of either one or all of your script.

Take a good look in your php error log, you might get a better explanation about what's missing and what is wrong. Your code supposed to be running well if you had `session_start()` in the beginning of each script that uses session.

If you don't explicitly call `session_start()`, then the variable `$_SESSION` is nothing more than a user defined variable, so in the first script you assign a value to a user defined variable, and in the second script you merely call to a non existent user defined variable. And be caution that php is case sensitive, `$_SESSION` is not the same as `$_Session`.

There is no way a variable can be overwritten remotely unless they were assigned by reference, take a look at this example:

```
$b = 1;
$a =& $b;
echo $a; // will output 1
$b = 2;
echo $a; // will output 2
```

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) is a nice explanation of how references works in php.

Comment: Yes, i also call session_start() in all page.Before clearing the session variable, the local variable hold the values. Local variable lost the values after clearing the session values,it is related on giving the same name on Local and session variables. Now i found a point in php.ini, this is [register_globals On].Now i change to it to [register_globals Off] and then there is no effect on local variable after clearing the session variable.How do u think about my change?

Comment: Well, you did the right thing, that's the only explanation besides the absent of `session_start()`. Here's a short explanation, theoritically when you have `register_globals` on, `$_SESSION['var']` actually calls to a variable called `$var`, that's the same as calling `$_POST['var']` and `$_GET['var']`, that's why assigning empty text to a session variable is the same as assigning to the variable itself, there's a good discussion of it in here: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.php/browse_thread/thread/bac6f1c426ef4b22/c3b0666dea7d75fd